# Redux selector syntax

Tags: redux

how does this function work?

```
    export const thingySelector = createSelector(
      (state: RootState) => state.thingy.data,
      (data) => data
    );
```

BR Dan

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to read the [Deriving Data with Selectors](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors) documentation, and specifically the [Writing Memoized Selectors with Reselect](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors#writing-memoized-selectors-with-reselect) section, for the complete understanding of these selector functions and why they are useful/powerful.

## Basic Gist

The basic gist how the `createSelector` function works is that it takes 1 or more "input selector" functions, e.g. the `(state: RootState) => state.thingy.data` of your example, and a single "output selector" that takes the returned value(s) of the inputs and computes an output value, e.g. `data => /* compute some value from data */`.

The results of the inputs are internally memoized when the computed selector function is called and it's ***only when*** these input values change that the output function is called to recompute the derived output value.

Example from documentation

> ```
> const state = {
>   a: {
>     first: 5
>   },
>   b: 10
> }
>
> const selectA = state => state.a
> const selectB = state => state.b
>
> const selectA1 = createSelector([selectA], a => a.first)
>
> const selectResult = createSelector([selectA1, selectB], (a1, b) => {
>   console.log('Output selector running')
>   return a1 + b
> })
>
> const result = selectResult(state)
> // Log: "Output selector running"
> console.log(result)
> // 15
>
> const secondResult = selectResult(state)
> // No log output
> console.log(secondResult)
> // 15
> ```
>
> Note that the second time we called `selectResult`, the "output
> selector" didn't execute. Because the results of `selectA1` and
> `selectB` were the same as the first call, `selectResult` was able to
> return the memoized result from the first call.

### Examples

It's actually incorrect to write a selector function that simply outputs its input.

```js
// This selector does nothing useful
export const thingySelector = createSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.thingy.data,
  (data) => data
);
```

but, assuming data is an object, maybe writing a selector function that transformed the selected state or did some work like converting it to an array, this is a useful selector.

Examples

```js
export const selectThingyKeys = createSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.thingy.data,
  (data) => Object.keys(data)
);

export const selectThingyValues = createSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.thingy.data,
  (data) => Object.values(data)
);
```

A common strategy is to have the selector functions select only 1-level deep into a reference, so your example could be broken up a bit more like the following.

```js
export const selectThingy = (state: RootState) => state.thingy;

export const selectThingyData = createSelector(
  selectThingy,
  thingy => thingy.data
);
```

If you needed to compute derived state from two different areas of the app state:

```js
export const selectThingy = (state: RootState) => state.thingy;

export const selectStuff = (state: RootState) => state.stuff;

export const selectHiddenStuff = createSelector(
  [selectStuff],
  stuff => stuff.hidden,
);

export const selectThingyData = createSelector(
  selectThingy,
  thingy => thingy.data
);

export const selectHiddenDataStuff = createSelector(
  [selectThingy, selectHiddenStuff],
  [thingy, hiddenStuff] => {
    // ... compute & return hidden thingy stuff, etc
  }
);
```

To select the derived hidden thingy data stuff the UI need only call the `selectHiddenDataStuff` selector and it doesn't need to concern itself with the actual state shape.

```js
const data = useAppSelector(selectHiddenDataStuff);
```

Comment: Thank you man for your effort! I will read and digest.